# how can we replace a file by retrieving it by ID column

Tags: document-library

I want to replace the existing document in SharePoint Document Library with a new document with different name. how can we replace a file by retrieving it by ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Update the new document for the given ID and then update the Name property.

**Update** 
The code is as follows.

```
private static void UpdateDocumentAndRename(string DocumentLibraryName, string NewDocumentName, Uri SiteUrl, string DocumentToBeUploadedUrl)
    {
        using (SPSite Site = new SPSite(SiteUrl.ToString()))
        {
            using (SPWeb Web = Site.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(DocumentToBeUploadedUrl))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", DocumentToBeUploadedUrl);

                SPFolder docLib = Web.GetList(DocumentLibraryName).RootFolder;

                // Prepare to upload
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DocumentToBeUploadedUrl);
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(DocumentToBeUploadedUrl);

                // Upload document
                SPFile spFile = docLib.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);
                docLib.Update();


                //Rename the file
                spFile.Item["Name"] = NewDocumentName;
                docLib.Update();

                if (docLib.RequiresCheckout)
                {
                    spFile.CheckIn("File checked in after it was updated with new document and renamed", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                    spFile.Publish("File published");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**PS** - please mark it as answer if found useful.

Comment: Can you please share the code to do it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with code. Please check.